# Delete Google Sheet rows matching multiple criteria with custom formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I have a [Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v_SSOloqZkzyjKQYfHLkmmRCWd64wOD6dPlWfN_TFK0/edit?usp=sharing) where I am trying to remove multiple rows matching any one of a vector of values using (`Filter by condition -> Custom formula`).

For this example, let's say I want to remove the rows with id (column A) values matching either 2 or 4. This works if the values are at the top of the range:

```
=MATCH(A:A, 2, 4)

id      name
2       h
4       d
327432  a
358105  pp
1       f
Sunday  dd
```

However, if they are at the bottom of the range, I am unable to specify the [`search_type`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) (`=MATCH(A:A, 2, 4, 0)` does not work)

```
id      name
1       h
Sunday  d
327432  a
358105  pp
2       f
4       dd
```

No combination of `AND`, `OR`, `QUERY`, `+`, `*`, `|`, or `REGEXMATCH` appears to do the trick. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- select Custom formula
- type in **`=(A2<>2)*(A2<>4)`**

  [image: 0]

  [image: 0]

---

- if you want to delete them completely, use this formula pasting it into **C1** cell:

  ```
  =FILTER(A:B, REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A:A), "[^2|4]"))
  ```

  and then copy range **C:D** and press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`V`**</kbd>

Comment: @jsta answer updated

Comment: If I have an `id` that is `22` it will get removed by this command...

Comment: in that case, do it like this: `=FILTER(A:B, NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A:A), "^2$|^4$")))`